nodriver failed to connect to browser into docker container
Id like to create a docker image that scrapes some sites using python code.
I use x11vnc for a virtual monitor, firefox-esr as browser and nodriver as python scraper.
Actually I can start a container and I can see the virtual monitor through TightVNC. I can start firefox-esr from interactive shell but if I use nodriver, passing /usr/bin/firefox-esr as executable path, it can't start browser and raise
            ---------------------
            Failed to connect to browser
            ---------------------
            One of the causes could be when you are running as root.
            In that case you need to pass no_sandbox=True 

Anyone can help me, please?
EDIT
This is my Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y x11vnc xvfb firefox-esr && \
    mkdir ~/.vnc && \
    touch ~/.vnc/passwd

RUN x11vnc -storepasswd "password" ~/.vnc/passwd
ENV DISPLAY=:1.0

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt install python3 -y
RUN apt install python3-pip -y


ADD start_all.sh /tmp/start_all.sh
CMD /tmp/start_all.sh

and the script executed when container starts
#!/bin/bash

Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16 &
DISPLAY=:1.0
export DISPLAY

# python3 main.py &

/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :1.0 -usepw -forever

The python code that I use to init nodriver browser is
ex_path = "/usr/bin/firefox-esr"
b_args = ['--private-window']
browser = await nodriver.start(browser_executable_path=ex_path, browser_args=b_args, headless=False, no_sandbox=True)

If I run firefox-esr from the container bash I can navigate with it. So, why the library cant execute firefox??
Maybe I can attach after browser starts?

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  It sounds like your setup includes an X server, a desktop browser, and also your scraping code; would this setup match better to a virtual-machine setup?

To create a minimal reproducible example need a repository ahahah
You got the structure right and I know that a vm is better, but I need a container sadly.

I went through this today as well. I'm using Chrome but I assume it would work the same as Firefox.
I've done a lot of debugging since the error is not that verbose, and while debugging I discovered that the real exception is a "Connection refused" thrown by asyncio.
Ended up passing headless=True and sandbox=False and it finally helped me get through this exception.
This is the configuration that worked :
driver = await uc.start(
    headless=True, sandbox=False
)


same error when adding browser_executable_path. show dockerfile

You shouldn't add browser_executable_path, it's a param that I use on my script to customize my chrome path. I will remove it from the answer as it may mislead people.

Thanks. In my case, I needed to install more xorg warez in the container

If you use headless browser some sites can block you. I need a head
